# What is the best way to style a vertical table with split background

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-table, bootstrap-4

How can I organize and style this data on a split background using css and html?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that layout of yours (if that's what you want right?), you need to collapse your table border for that, to avoid white gaps. add a special class for `tr` that represents the `thead` and style it accordingly. follow the pattern with `<tr><th></th><td></td></tr>`. use text-align to center them with right to `th` and left to `td`.

```css
td, th {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 250px;
}

th { background: #E9EADA; text-align: right; }
td { background: #FCFCFC; text-align: left; }

.table-header > * {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #238E98;
}

table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-header">
    <th>Details</th>
    <td>---</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```